# What's the fastest way to convert an image to a flat list of RGB values

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert an image to a flat list of rgb values. For instance if we had the (3, 3) image that happened to have to following rgb matrix:

(5, 10, 12) (13, 16, 12) (10, 14, 2)

(6, 3, 6) (13, 14, 15) (50, 60 210)

(12, 15, 19) (20, 13, 27) (100, 200, 210)

What I want to do fast is produce:
[5, 10, 12, 13, 16, 12, 10, 14, 2,
6, 3, 6, 13, 14, 15, 50, 60 210,
12, 15, 19, 20, 13, 27, 100, 200, 210]

Here is what I am doing currently

```
def flatten(matrix):
        def decompose(row):
            retrow = []
            for item in row:
                retrow = retrow + item
            return retrow
        retlist = []
        for row in matrix:
            retlist = retlist + decompose(row)
        return retlist
curimg = #load in the pillow img
curimg = np.array(curimg).tolist()
curimg = flatten(curimg)
```

I'm doing this for a machine learning application, and I have a ton of images I need to do this for. I'm pretty sure my asymptotic runtime is fine, but I want to make sure i'm not doing this unnecessarily slow.

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten numpy arrays directly, without copying the data:

```
flat_img = np.array(curimg).ravel()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand I think you can use `[chain][1]` from `itertools` as follows:

```
my_tuple = [(5, 10, 12),(13, 16, 12),(10, 14, 2),(6, 3, 6), (13, 14, 15), (50, 60, 210),(12, 15, 19), (20, 13, 27), (100, 200, 210)]

from itertools import chain

x = chain(*my_tuple)
print list(x)

OUTPUT:
[5, 10, 12, 13, 16, 12, 10, 14, 2, 6, 3, 6, 13, 14, 15, 50, 60, 210, 12, 15, 19, 20, 13, 27, 100, 200, 210]
```